# Use a slider in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Really simple question. I wish to create `GUI` with a simple `plot` that changes something with a slider. I have been using the GUI and have a slider+text on a panel and axies1. So for starters I just wish to have the slider going from 1:10 (no specific increments) and scaling the y-values (by 1:10). I have imported my data into the GUI, so leaving out the generic auto-generate code I have:

Under Graphslide_OpeningFcn

```
handles.OutAirTemp = OutAirTemp;
handles.SupAirTemp = SupAirTemp;
guidata(hObject,handles);
handles.a = get(handles.slider2,'Value');
plot(handles.SupAirTemp,handles.a*handles.OutAirTemp)
```

Under slider2_Callback

```
a = get(hObject,'Value')
```

So clearly I am missing something! Any pointers, theory or code will be greatly received.

`Edit1`
There was no error message for the above. It however didn't change the graph when sliding the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider callback is the one executed once you release it. In your code above, you need to update the values that you plot in the axes in the slider callback; you're pretty close actually. I think moving those lines:

```
handles.a = get(handles.slider2,'Value');
plot(handles.SupAirTemp,handles.a*handles.OutAirTemp)
```

inside the slider callback will do what you want.

As an aside, you can look at the following code to generate a simple GUI with an axes, a slider and an edit box in which the current value of the slider is displayed.
You can set up the properties of the slider such as the min, max and step as well to get the behaviour you want.

```
function GUI_slider
clc
clear

%// Create GUI controls
handles.figure = figure('Position',[100 100 500 500],'Units','Pixels');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[60,100,400,300]);

handles.Slider1 = uicontrol('Style','slider','Position',[60 20 400 50],'Min',0,'Max',1,'SliderStep',[.1 .1],'Callback',@SliderCallback);

handles.Edit1 = uicontrol('Style','Edit','Position',[250 450 100 20],'String','Update Me');
handles.Text1 = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[180 450 60 20],'String','Slider Value');

handles.xrange = 1:20; %// Use to generate dummy data to plot.

guidata(handles.figure,handles); %// Update the handles structure.

    function SliderCallback(~,~) %// This is the slider callback, executed when you release the it or press the arrows at each extremity. 

        handles = guidata(gcf);

        SliderValue = get(handles.Slider1,'Value');
        set(handles.Edit1,'String',num2str(SliderValue));

        plot(handles.xrange,SliderValue*rand(1,20),'Parent',handles.axes1);
    end

end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It worked!! Thank you yet again. I left the original `plot` in there so that it has the unscaled graph there upon start up. It then reloads the axes with the scaled graph which is just what I want.

Comment: On a similar(ish) note, when using GUI, do I need to use `clc`
`clear all`
`close all` to clear memory at the start of the GUI? I'm guessing not but thought it best to check and that it is not worth a whole question.

Comment: Oh indeed that's a reflex of mine at the beginning of scripts to use clear and clc haha you don't necessarily have to do this as it might cause trouble if you use multiple GUIs for instance :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what error message you get or what the problem is, so we can't guess what's wrong. However, there are a few things I can see are wrong:

- you probably need to specify the handle of the axes on which to plot when issuing the `plot` command
- for your `slider2_Callback`, you probably need

  `handles.a = get(hObject,'Value')
  guidata(hObject,handles);`
- for your `Graphslide_OpeningFcn`, you don't say where `OutAirTemp` and `SupAirTemp` come from. I would also issue the `guidata` at the end of the function rather than in the middle as your are doing.

Comment: There was no error message. It just didnt change the graph when I slid the slider. `OutAirTemp` and `SupAirTemp` are imported and are plotting nicely. I have moved guidata to the end of the function Graphslide_OpeningFcn. I added in handles.axes1 but this changed nothing. What do you mean by your first bullet point? Thanks

Comment: Look at the doc for `plot`, I meant `plot(handles.ax,handles.SupAirTemp,handles.a*handles.OutAirTemp)` where `handles.ax` is the handles to your axes (obtained elsewhere in the GUI, where you first create the axes). However, as @Benoit_11 pointed out, the `plot` call should be in the slider callback, not in the GUI opening function.