# Using a slider in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

Following the hints given by [Benoit_11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3352541/benoit-11) in [Use a slider in MATLAB GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632952/use-a-slider-in-matlab-gui), I started adapting his code so to fit my case.

I noticed that when the vector `SliderValue*(1:0.1:20).^2` is modified to `SliderValue*(1:dt:20).^2`, with `dt = 0.1`, the plot does not show anything. This is required as I want to use an expression defined by variables.

A second question: how can I manually define the axes ranges?

My code:

```
%function GUI_slider

    % GUI Controls
    
    dt = 0.1;
    t = 0:0.1:100;
    
    handles.figure = figure('Position', [100 100 1000 500], 'Units', 'Pixels');
    handles.axes1 = axes('Units', 'Pixels', 'Position', [60, 120, 900, 300]);
    handles.Slider1 = uicontrol('Style', 'slider', 'Position', [60 40 400 25], ...
                                'Min', min(t), 'Max', max(t), 'SliderStep', [.01 .01], ...
                                'Callback', @SliderCallback);
    handles.Edit1 = uicontrol('Style', 'Edit', 'Position', [150 453 100 20], ...
                              'String', 'Click on slider');
    handles.Text1 = uicontrol('Style', 'Text', 'Position', [70 450 70 20], ...
                              'String', 'Slider Value:');
    handles.xrange = 1:dt:20;           %// Use to generate dummy data to plot
    guidata(handles.figure, handles);   %// Update the handles structure

    function SliderCallback(~,~)        %// This is the slider callback, executed when you release  it or press the arrows at each extremity. 

        handles = guidata(gcf);

        SliderValue = get(handles.Slider1, 'Value');
        set(handles.Edit1, 'String', num2str(SliderValue));

        plot(handles.xrange, SliderValue*(1:0.1:20).^2, 'Parent', handles.axes1);

    end
%end
```

What should I correct to have it running?

Comment: I've rolled back your latest edit, as it would invalidate any existing answers. Please only make edits to clarify your question; if you have qualms about an answer, please leave a comment on that.

Comment: Your code works the same for me if I replace `0.1` with `dt`. If the line `function GUI_slider` and matching `end` are not commented out, then `SliderCallback` is a nested function that has access to the parent's `dt` variable. The solution below would not be necessary.

Comment: Maybe your plot doesn't show anything because you've fixed the axes somewhere else, and the `plot` command is plotting outside the field of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cris Luengo noted, if un-comment first line ( `%function GUI_slider` ) and last line ( `%end`), `dt` would be considered as a global variable for all sub-functions inside your main function ( `GUI_slider`), Therefore, `dt` is accessible inside the sub-function `SliderCallback(~,~)` and you can run the code with  `SliderValue*(1:dt:20).^2`.

For the second question, using the function `axis` you can manually set axes range:

```
axis([x_min, x_man, y_min, y_max]);
```

or

```
set(gca, 'xlim', [x_min, x_max]);
set(gca, 'ylim', [y_min, y_max]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not passing `dt` to the inner `SliderCallback` function, so it doesn't know what `dt` is (you should actually get an error telling you that). It should work if you add `dt` to the function definition

```
function SliderCallback(~,~,dt)
```

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan. Unfortunately your tip doesn't solve my problem. I still do not obtain any plot results (as I do when dt is replaced by 0.1). I have included your tip and the definition of t in my question, so it works as a standalone piece of code.